# Nvidia quadro 4800/ubuntu 20.04 will not detect second monitor on MacPro 3,1

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, mac

Nvidia quadro 4800/ubuntu 20.04 will not detect second monitor on MacPro 3,1. The monitor was working just fine in mac os x. But after installing Ubuntu 20.04 the nvidia driver only sees one monitor. Also it seems that only one dvi port is working/not detected.